# Create Value in Registery

Tags: registry, c

I want to create value name "NoDrives" in registery in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer] for hiding drives. But as there is no value, i need to create it. I tried finding in msdn. There is a function to create key but not value. I also used RegSetValueEx. But it says error 2 which means file not found.

Comment: Ask this is StackOverflow. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexa & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa

Comment: I want to create value not key

Comment: Did you check the second URL?

Comment: I used that function. But it returns error 2 which means not found.

Comment: Ops I need to run it as admin

Comment: I also am trying to write dword type value. But it shows error 24?something and regedit shows invalid 32 bit value. Can you show me an example.